# Variável undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Se coloco a variável `contador` fora da `function`, o retorno no alert é `undefined`. Porém  se coloco a mesma dentro da `function`, me retorna o valor correto mas não incrementa. O que estou fazendo errado?

```
var qtdeCampos = 0;
var contador = 0;

function addCampos() {

    var validacampo = $('#campo'+contador).val();
    alert(validacampo);

    var elem = document.getElementById("produto");
    var prod = elem.options[elem.options.selectedIndex];
    var elem2 = document.getElementById("versao");
    var versao = elem2.options[elem2.options.selectedIndex];

    var prodversao = prod.text+" | "+versao.text;

    if (validacampo == prodversao){
        alert("Não é possivel adicionar produto repetido");
    }else{
        var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
        //Criando o elemento DIV;
        var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
        //Definindo atributos ao objFilho:
        objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);

       //Inserindo o elemento no pai:
       objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
       //Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
       document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<input readonly type='text' class='prod' id='campo"+qtdeCampos+"' name='campo[]' value='"+prodversao+"'> <input type='button' onclick='removerCampo("+qtdeCampos+")' value='X'>";
       qtdeCampos++;
       contador++;
       document.getElementById("cont").value = qtdeCampos;
    }
}

function removerCampo(id) {
    var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
    var objFilho = document.getElementById("filho"+id);

    //Removendo o DIV com id específico do nó-pai:
    var removido = objPai.removeChild(objFilho);
}
```

Comment: Onde `contador` está `undefined`? É em alguma parte do código que você postou (se for, favor indicar a linha) ou em algum outro código que você não postou?

Comment: Então na verdade a função desta variavel é acrescentar o valor 0,1,2... quantas vezes a pessoa clicar no botão `var validacampo = $('#campo'+contador).val();` porem ela não adiciona o numero. mas se eu colocar a var contador dentro da função ela funciona

Comment: Por que não `validacaoCampo = validacaoCampo + 1` ? Não está claro que você quer e está faltando código (sua função não termina, por exemplo)

Comment: Raul, faz um teste, remove o `.val()` e deixa somente o `$('#campo'+contador)`. As vezes está buscando o campo mas a funcao `val()` é o problema. Fazendo parecer que não está buscando o campo correto. Aparentemente o seu código deveria funcionar perfeitamente, suspeito que seja o `val()`;

Comment: @rubico tentei sem o val() e tbm não funcionou

Comment: @pablo estou tentando pegar o conteudo de um input text e o input text conforme a pessoa vai adicionando vai acrescentando o valor no id por exemplo id="campo1" id="campo2" e assim por diante (Adicionei o resto da função)

Comment: Reveja minha resposta abaixo! Analisando, identifiquei que o problema pode não ser o contador...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seu problema seja que você está tentando obter um elemento '#campo0' que ainda não existe, e não é problema com o 'contador'. Você deve ter pelo menos 1 elemento "'#campo'+contador" para efetuar essa chamada no JQuery. Tente fazer o seguinte, substitua a linha :

```
var validacampo = $('#campo'+contador).val();
```

Por:

```
// Verifica se já tem algum campo inserido, senão não tenta chamar
    if(contador > 0) {
    var validacampo = $('#campo'+(contador-1)).val();
    alert(validacampo);
    } else {
  //Seta para null apenas para não entrar no alert "Não é possivel adicionar produto repetido"
    validacampo = null;
    }
```

Comment: Se a variável está no *top-level* (i.e. fora de qualquer função) ela já é global, com ou sem o `var` na frente.

Comment: Então ja fiz isso e não funcionou

Comment: É que tem pouco conteúdo para analisar. Disponibilize a função. Neste trecho de código a variavel 'contador' nem mesmo é incrementada...

Comment: @Jhonnyjks adicionei o resto da função

Comment: Pronto! Testei dessa forma e passou! Veja a resposta novamente!

Comment: @Jhonnyjks Então também pensei nisso porem substitui o que vc me passou e ainda continua undefined :(

da uma olhada na imagem [link]http://www.ideaestud.io/sites/helpdesk/wp-content/themes/supportdesk/js/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.jpg

Comment: Dê um alert('#campo'+contador) no lugar do alert q tem e verifica se o id gerado (algo como #campo2) realmente existe. Se não existir, talvez seja necessário decrementar 1 unidade, ficando: $('#campo'+(contador-1)).val()

Comment: @Jhonnyjks Funcionou vlw mesmo em! So que agora tive outro problema eu estava fazendo a verificação do produto que a pessoa estava inserindo com o ultimo produto inserido e mesmo assim a pessoa consegue inserir duas vezes o mesmo produto vou ter que adicionar os produtos dentro de uma array para verificar todos os produtos que já foram inseridos! mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Para não bagunçar esta questão já resolvida, se você não conseguir resolver este outro problema, crie outra pergunta informando o código dos dois selects e da lista "produto | versao" com uns 3 itens.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, remova a negativação por favor! Estou tentando ganhar a vida kkk

Comment: E por que você acha que fui eu que negativou rsrs? Bom, não posso remover o que não votei, mas já que o AP está satisfeito, toma um +1 pra compensar o -1, seja ele de quem for.

Comment: Pensei por causa do comentário útil... kkk... vlw

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode estar acontecendo por causa de escopo de definição de variável.

No exemplo abaixo `contador` é definida duas vezes, uma no escopo global e outra em uma funcão que contém a função `addCampos`. O resultado é o seguinte:

> Global: 0
>   wrapperAddCampos: undefined
>   addCampos: undefined

Entretando, se você comentar a linha 6 (`var contador;`), seu resultado será o seguinte:

> Global: 0
>   wrapperAddCampos: 0
>   addCampos: 0

Isso acontece porque o escopo de variável é herdado hierarquicamente; se variáveis de mesmo nome forem definidas em escopos descendentes, os escopos subsequentes receberão uma referência para a nova variável de mesmo nome.

```js
var qtdeCampos = 0;
var contador = 0;

function wrapperAddCampos(){
  
  var contador;
  
  document.write('wrapperAddCampos: ' + contador + "<br/>");

  function addCampos() {
  document.write('addCampos: ' + contador + "<br/>");
    alert(validacampo);
    contador++;
  }

  addCampos();
}

document.write('Global: ' + contador + "<br/>");
wrapperAddCampos();
```